# trying do the math equations, i tried searching similar expressions

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

```
\begin{document}

 \Lambda =\{\lambda1, \lambda2, \dots, \lambda\def\abs\Lambda\}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: What are `\def` and `\abs` supposed to result in? Probably a hand-drawn image of the expected output could help clarify this.

Comment: `\Lambda` and `\lambda` can only be used in math mode. You could start by placing your equation inside of an `equation` environment.

Comment: `\def` is a TeX "primitive". Why is `\def\abs\Lambda` in the formula?

Comment: I really advise you to go through this: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10 - all the time you spend there to understand it will be rewarded by *lots* of time saved in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I updated this answer after the OP provided some additional information, in a comment, as to what `\def\abs\Lambda` was supposed to mean.)

If you wish to typeset the statement that "`\Lambda` is a set which contains `\lambda_{1}` (not `\lambda1`), `\lambda_{2}`, etc. through `\lambda_{\abs{\Lambda}}` as its elements" as an unnumbered displayed equation, you could do so with the following code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert} % to display absolute value fn.
\begin{document}
\[
\Lambda =\{ \lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \dots, \lambda_{\abs{\Lambda}} \}
\]
\end{document}
```

Observe that `\[` and `\]` are used in this example to initiate and terminate an unnumbered displayed equation. If you need to typeset the equation inline math mode instead of display math mode, you should not employ `\[` and `\]` and, instead, write

```
$\Lambda =\{ \lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \dots, \lambda_{\abs{\Lambda}} \}$
```

A final comment: Presumably, you've defined `\abs{\Lambda}` suitably elsewhere in your document -- possibly as the *cardinality* of the set `\Lambda`?.

Comment: i want do it same as photo attahced

Comment: @QussayA.Ameer What photo attached?

Comment: can you check the link please, uploaded it here. https://ibb.co/nDcT0Kp

Comment: @QussayA.Ameer - You should really place this supplemental graphical information in the body of your query.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for the typo fixes. :-)